# System properties and parallel test execution in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

One of our classes uses a system property to load a configuration file. In a particular test case, we set this property to an invalid value to check the behavior of the class under test (CUT) in this situation.

The same class is also used transitively in various integration tests. Since we are using JUnit Jupiter's [parallel test execution capabilities](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution), we are witnessing race conditions in those integration tests that are using the CUT under the hood. They are failing because the system property is sometimes still invalid.

The parallelism itself is configured globally via the Maven Surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
                junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor=1
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Consequently, all tests run in parallel per default. The CUT looks like this:

```
class AttributesProviderTest {

    @Test
    @ResourceLock( value = SYSTEM_PROPERTIES, mode = READ_WRITE )
    void invalid_attributes_file_should_yield_UncheckedIOException() throws Exception {
        final Properties backup = new Properties();
        backup.putAll( System.getProperties() );

        final String attributesFile = "foo";
        System.setProperty( AttributesProvider.ATTRIBUTES_FILE_PROPERTY, attributesFile );

        assertThatThrownBy( AttributesProvider::getTestInstance )
                .isExactlyInstanceOf( UncheckedIOException.class )
                .hasMessage( "Cannot read attributes file '" + attributesFile + "'." );

        System.setProperties( backup );
    }

    // Some other tests...

}
```

As it can be seen, we are trying to [synchronize](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution-synchronization) the system property access. However, if I have understood correctly, this only works for other `@ResourceLock`-annotated tests, and does not magically synchronize system property access in general?

Is there a way to fix the race condition (without annotating all other tests)? Some ideas:

- Ensure the CUT is executed sequentially at the beginning (or some other sort of synchronization).
- Refactor the CUT and invoke corresponding file-reading method with a parameter directly.
- Throw away the test case.

Comment: The ResourceLock only works on those tests which have the `@ResourceLock` annotation which I assume the other tests which fail do not have..? Furthermore from my point of view it means you have not real unit tests you have in contradiction integration tests which means you can't parallelize them.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for clarifying `@ResourceLock`. And yes, the failing tests are not unit tests; as I said: "The same class is also used transitively in various integration tests." I will rephrase the question to make this clear.